# Walled cities for Purim other than Jerusalem

Tags: halacha, calendar, purim, geography

The holiday of Purim is unique in that some locations celebrate it on different days. The rule is: if the city was walled at the time of Joshua's conquest of the Land of Israel then they celebrate on the 15th of Adar, while everyone else celebrates on the 14th of Adar.

Are there any cities nowadays that celebrate Purim only on the 15th of Adar aside from Jerusalem?

[Things to consider include (but are not limited to) the lists of cities from the book of Joshua (eg [Chapter 12](http://mechon-mamre.org/p/pt/pt0612.htm#9)), and the city Shushan itself. Do we know where these are? Do any Jews live there?]

EDIT: To clarify, I am looking for cities that celebrate (as I said above) **only** on the 15th like Jerusalem does, not cities that have some doubt and celebrate both days.

Comment: https://net-sah.org/faq/26636

Comment: https://ph.yhb.org.il/05-17-01/ רק לגבי עיר אחת בלבד נותרה מסורת ברורה שהיא מוקפת חומה מימות יהושע בן נון, הלא היא ירושלים עיר קדשנו ותפארתנו, ורק בה עושים בזמן הזה את הפורים ביום ט"ו.

Comment: @JoelK Nonsense... (His dad is the Rav in beit el and ruled long ago against shushan purim and now he's stuck defending that position with all its difficulties. He has such a big pulpit though that soon people will believe it)

Comment: It reads to me like he's being descriptive here, rather than prescriptive, but maybe you're correct and there's an agenda behind it

Comment: @Joel theres too much to say for a comment, but there are lots of places in Israel with varying degrees of proof from incontrovertable to plausible. Some rabbis, often of a hashkafic persuasion that doesnt approve of looking outside at the metzius instead of just reading achronim, work hard to combine many achronish questions to put any tiny bit of doubt in each case. Others look outside their windows and study the history. From 48 to 67 all the former group forgot their chumras and had West Jerusalem celebrate just the 15th. Go figure. B"H with time more and more are noting the reality outsde

Comment: @joelk I encourage you to read all the nuances of a few cases to see what I mean. Every city is it's own unique sugya, but after 2 or 3 you get the gist of all of them. A classic example is Lod. The Talmud says Lod is a walled city, and there's a big famous church in Lod from Talmudic times. The church didn't stand up and move so what's not clear? Lod was a known major transportation hub continuously the whole time even though there wasn't a fixed Jewish population till recently. Only someone with an agenda wouldn't say, ya there's a tradition that Lod is Lod just like we know Paris is Paris.

Comment: There is a teshuva from Rav Ovadia ben Rav Ya'akov Yosef (grandson of the Rishon leTzion) doing the rounds in Beit Shemesh this year. He paskens that certain neighborhoods in Ramat Beit Shemesh should be celebrating Purim on the 15th (and that anyone who wants to be machmir can also do the 14th without brachot). Whether anyone will listen to this pesak is another question.

Comment: @JoelK if so, then that's quite meikil that he limits it to only some neighborhoods.

Comment: Three neighborhoods are contiguously inhabited and end up very near to the walls of Tel Yarmut. (The neighborhood closest to the walls has only been inhabited for a few months.) There is a bit of a break between those neighborhoods and the rest of the city; in the rest of the city he says one should be machmir to do two days.

Comment: @JoelK well if you're around there or can influence anyone there please support that effort. Volunteer to read Megillah in a shul on the 15th even if 2 people come. Give shaloch manos to people who would be otherwise unaware. Invite people to a seudah. Even though these halachot of Samukh are literally designed to change every year with the new circumstances and not care about minhag, inertia remains a strong Jewish trait. Now's unfortunately the most important time to establish facts on the ground. If you need more sources to present to a shul rabbi or something let me know how I can help.

Comment: Thanks for the offer. I know a number of local rabbanim are currently having discussions with Rav Asher Weiss on the topic. My feeling is that if he comes out publicly that will carry a lot of weight in Ramat Beit Shemesh. There is also this that happened a couple days ago https://vinnews.com/2022/03/06/rabbi-moshe-bransdorfer-paskens-bet-shemesh-neighborhood-must-celebrate-15th-adar-as-well/. Seems like every year there is more of a movement in the direction of 15th Adar - question is if and when it will reach a critical mass.

Comment: @Joel I agree RAW would be a big name. My impression of his derekh hapsak is he'd be pretty hesitant to do this, but I admit he's quite a wildcard sometimes. That article is so embarrassing that he has to explicitly pretend to be ignoring archaeology because of charedi politics. As if looking outside is archaeology and as if there's a category of archaeology that is de jure invalidating. It's not just yarmuth btw, but like 6 other Tels in the general vicinity of the metropolis. You have to be blind to think the whole thing might not be Samukh to a wall. Same with Gush Dan, but I digress...

Comment: Btw a good thought experiment is to realize the arguments for needing some explicit tradition of continuous use for tekhelet are much stronger than those for needing some tradition here since we know gentile walled cities count as well as cities far away from Israel where all the Jews were in the days of Yhoshua, not to mention how much we rely on non jewish-info for gvulot haaretz questions, as opposed to tekhelet which has practical (how did they make it) and conceptual (it's just an arbitrary ritual object) concerns. Now go wonder why so many Israelis wear tekhelet but read only on the 14th

Answer (score 3):

Hebron is know to be Ir Miklat - so it had a wall with many gates. Hence, there is dispute if its wall indeed makes it a walled city or not. Therefore, in Hebron and Kiryat Arba purim is holidayed on both days.

[Here](http://www.yeshiva.org.il/midrash/printShiur.aspx/7056) is a source in Hebrew that lists more places that are sofek mukafin.

> הערים שיש לגביהן ספק הן: טבריה, חברון, שכם, יפו, לוד, עזה, צפת, עכו, חיפה. ויש שהוסיפו שיש ספק לגבי: בית שאן, יריחו, באר שבע, רמלה. ובחוץ לארץ: צור, צידון, דמשק, איזמיר ובגדאד.‏

Comment: I specifically asked in the question about cities that celebrate **only** on the 15th. If you know of any who treat chevron that way, please edit it in. Otherwise, no vote from me.

Answer (score 2):

There are many debates and many customs, but Jeruselem is the only city where everybody treats it as a walled city only.

Some people keep purim in Tzvat on the 15th, some people in Acco do the same. But its' not universally agreed upon, the way it is in Jeruselem.

Comment: o you have any information about the people who you say keep just the 15th in tzfat and acko? Who's psak are they following? How many of them are there?

Comment: @DoubleAA Re: Acco and Tzfat, I imagine it's urban legend, passed on, as "I once was with a person who", as I've seen statements on the internet, but have never met a person who actually behaved that way.  And my friend who lives in Acco dismisses those who celebrate on the 15th as being incorrect, so he's never met them either.

Comment: There is a definite custom in Akko. Not everyone follows it.

Comment: How can there be a custom for a location, if not everyone in that location follows it?

Answer (score 2):

I heard that the city of Prague also had a wall around it in the days of Yehoshua

Comment: Hi Chana. This seems rather unlikely. Where did you hear this?

Comment: AFAIK Prague read on the 15th out of doubt, but the question was only asking about cities that definitely read on the 15th.

Comment: Welcome to Mi Yodeya Chana!

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://judaism.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/28499)

Comment: @donielf it does provide an answer.it's just wrong

Comment: @mevaqesh is right. VLQ queue deletion is for things posted in the answer box that literally make no attempt whatsoever to answer the the question, things like "I am also wondering about this too" or "Hi mom!". If you feel that the answer is *wrong*, poorly sourced, and/or unclear, the correct way to respond is to downvote it.

Answer (score 0):

The gemarah megillah (5b, Yerushalmi 1:1) cites a question as to whether or not Tiverya was considered a walled city from the times of Yehoshua. The question seems to be about the nature of the wall but it seems clear that they should celebrate on the 15th

There is a question as to which city in Iran is Shushan (Susa or Hamadan) - with poskim indicating that whichever it is, Jews in that city should celebrate on the 15th.

I know you didn't ask about cities which are in doubt and that some of these were covered by another answer but for the sake of completeness I am including them here as well. There seems to be a doubt about the city of Baghdad. The city of Tyre is also in question in this regard as is Provence, Saloniki

All sources come from my extrapolations of [this essay by Rabbi Jonathan Cohen](http://download.yutorah.org/2013/1053/Purim_To_Go_-_5771_Rabbi_Cohen.pdf)

Comment: I agree it's clear the original custom and the implied position of all the rishonim is that teveria reads only on the 15th (since we should and they did rule like Rebbe). Do you know anyone who practices this way?

Comment: (To be fair most articles and most people's knowledge on this esoteric topic are really underwhelming.)