# Did Aleppo Jews observe Purim on the 14th (regular) or 15th (Shushan Purim)?

Tags: history, purim, sephardi-mizrachi-eastern, shushan-purim

Did the Jews of Aleppo, Syria observe Purim on the 14th or 15th of Adar? Was it believed to be old enough for the latter?

Comment: possible dupe http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14963/759

Comment: To clarify, to read on the 15th of adar a city must have been walled at the time of yehoshua. This requires that it be old (as old as Yehoshua of course) but also that it have been walled at the time (It doesnt need to still be walled). I dont know how old Aleppo's wall was ,but according to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aleppo) "The old city was enclosed within an ancient wall" and wikipedia further states that it was settled as early as the period of Yehoshua. The question is just how old the wall was. A last concern is that according to some opinions, besides for Shushan (cont.)

Comment: only cities in Israel (wit the above requirements) read on the 15th.

Comment: @mevaqesh You may have something to add to http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/27676/759

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to Derech Eress, a book on the customs of Aleppo,the Jews used to celebrate 2 days of Purim out of Safek.

> ולכן נהגו לעשות פורים
>    שני ימים, אלא שקוראים את המגילה בלי ברכה: וכן היה מנהג ארם צובה מימי קדם,
>    שנהגו כל דיני פורים בשני הימים (וגם קראו בתורה בברכה - ורק על המגילה
>    (לא בירכו, כאמור). מנהג זה המשיך אצל המוסתערבים (התושבים הוותיקים)
>    גם לאחר שהגיעו המגורשים מספרד, אלא שלאחרונה התמזגו הקהילות
>    (קהילת הספרדים עם קהילת המוסתערבים), ובטלו כל דיני פורים ביום)
>    השני, מלבד קריאת המגילה (בלי ברכה), שנוהגת עד עצם היום הזה בארם
>    צובה.

My translation:
And therefore the tradition was to make Purim 2 days, but to read the megillah [on the second day] without a Berakhah. And this is the Minhag of Aram Soba from the olden days that all the traditions of Purim were practiced both days (and even read the Torah with a Berakhah, only on the Megillah there was no Berakhah). This Minhag continued with the orginal settlers of Aram Soba (before the Sephardim of the Spanish Inquisition). However, when the Musta'arbim combined with the Sepharadim, all the traditions faded, except the reading of the Megillah on Shushan Purim without a Berakhah, which still is practiced today in Halab.

Comment: This was the widespread tradition in all major middle eastern cities for all of recorded history. Only recently have people become lazy about it.