# Is Shushan Purim observed (in theory) in Shush, Iran?

Tags: halacha, calendar, purim, geography, cities

Shushan, Achashveirosh's capital, is identified with the modern Iranian archaeological site of [Susa](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susa). A city, [Shush](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shush,_Iran), has been established nearby.

**In modern-day Shush, (if any Jews lived there), what day would Purim be celebrated on?**

Ancient Susa had a wall since before the time of Yehoshua ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Susa#Proto-Elamite)), so that's not a problem.

The real question is, i suppose, **is the modern city close enough to the ancient one to be considered the same?**
I do know that in T'verya, even though the ancient city had a wall, the modern city (for the most part) does not celebrate Shushan Purim, because it isn't really so close. As for those who do, [Rabbi Daniel Sperber](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daniel_Sperber) says that it is a *minhag ta'ut*, a mistaken custom.

Comment: if they do, they do it differently 
https://vimeo.com/89234381

Comment: There are still Jews in Iran, I expect that this is not unique to Tehran and Isfahan

Comment: @ShmuelBrin I don't recall the source ATM, but it is identified with a city mentioned in Sefer Yehoshua. Also, people there *do* celebrate both days of Purim, out of safek/minhag avoteinu b'yadeinu.

Comment: Possible dupe? http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14963/759

Comment: In a deleted comment there^^^ a respected sefardi user of ours said he thought the custom in http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamadan was to keep the second day only for your reason

Comment: Where does R Sperber say this, and why?

Comment: @DoubleAA (1) Because they think Hamadan is Shushan, or because of the wall? (2) I don't have the exact source, but somewhere in *Minhagei Yisrael*. If it's important, i can try and find it. The reason is because modern-day T'verya is quite far from ancient T'verya. The ruins of ancient T'verya are in Park Berko, a couple miles outside of the city. And that's just Roman-era T'verya -- there are older ruins too. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamat_Tiberias

Comment: @Cnsersmoit Because they think it's Shushan.

Comment: @DoubleAA FWIW R. Ovadya casually assumes that Hamadan is Shushan in Hazon Ovadya as does his son in Yalkut Yosef.

Answer (score 1):

*Nitei Gavriel* ([53:4](http://hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=46446&st=&pgnum=302)) writes that they would only read it on the 14<sup>th</sup> of *Adar*, since we don't know exactly where the [original] city is located.

(*Credit: [Menachem](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/users/603/menachem)*)

Comment: Does he mean we don't know where in Shush the old city was, or we don't know that Shush is the right city?

Comment: How does he know that we don't know? It's no surprise that he has no family tradition on the matter, but perhaps Persian Jews do?

Comment: @DoubleAA We don't know that Shush (or any other city) is the right city.

Comment: Ah. That doesn't seem accurate though. Shushan was a big famous city historically and there's no doubt about its identification today TTBOMK.

Comment: @DoubleAA Fair point. btw can you identify the sefer he quotes "א"י"? I can't think of any sefer with those initials.

Comment: Sorry I can't see the link right now. My intial guess is Sefer Eretz Yisrael of R YM Tukachinksy

Comment: @DoubleAA I found what the *Nitei Gavriel* is basing himself on in "*[Ir Hakodesh Vehamikdash](http://www.teachittome.com/seforim2/seforim/ir_hakodesh_vehamikdash_3.pdf)*" from the same author, where he writes that from all the cities which were surrounded by a wall from the times of *Yehoshua*, none of them are known to us today except *Yerusholayim* exclusively.