Celebrating Shushan Purim in cities outside the Land of Israel
Is it customary to celebrate Shushan Purim also in cities outside the Land of Israel that had a wall from the days of Joshua ben Nun?

This question overlaps https://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/14963.

It does not matter if the city is in Israel or not (OC 688:1).

Notably, since in the days of Joshua there were virtually zero Jews outside Israel, this sort of implies we can trust gentile/public traditions about city location and status.
